# How to change the file extension of a specific selected file

Tags: powershell

I know how to change the extension of the entire file in a folder,but how am i supposed to change the specific selected file in the folder.

Comment: Please add further detail and a trial code you have written

Answer (score 3):

Lets say I have a folder with a bunch of text files. Some are car files and some are truck files. So example names would be car1,car2,truck1, truck2 etc. Now lets say I just want to change the extension for the car files. I can then filter off the file names (You can actually filter off any property like lastwrite dt/tm etc). In example below I change the extension for all files containing car in the file name. If you give more context on what you are trying to filter on I will adjust answer.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Temp2\Test\* | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*car*"}

foreach($file in $files)
{
   $newName = $file.Name -replace ".txt", ".doc"
   Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $newName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Rename-Item -path c:\docs\File.csv -newname Report.xlsx
```

Comment: You may want to expand on your answer, Vivek, and give a little more context to the situation ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)).

Answer (score 1):

As other have pointed out, the command you're looking for is [**`Rename-Item`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.3)

For added safety, you can use [**`[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.changeextension?view=net-7.0) to create the new file name in case you have a weird file name (e.g. `bills.txt.json`)

Here's an example script that changes all the `.txt` files in a folder to `.json`

```cs
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($_.Name, ".json") }
```